# Accessing embedded resource as "a file"

Tags: c++, embedded-resource

I'm trying to glue together two libraries where
`lib1` is providing scripts to `lib2`.
The libraries are used in c++11 code I'm writing. I can't modify those libs.

Scripts in `lib1` are embedded into the shared object with https://github.com/vector-of-bool/cmrc.

The content of each script can be accessed with an iterator, like so

```
cmrc::embedded_filesystem fs=cmrc::hpo::get_filesystem()
auto script1 = fs.open("script1")
# use iterator for script1...
```

However, `lib2` function requires 'physical' file: `void file(const char *);`

I know I can dump content from `lib1` iterator to a temp file, read it with `lib2` and then remove the file. This solution sounds rather sub optimal and I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: OS-specific solutions OK? Standard C++ doesn't have many options besides that temporary file.

Comment: Yes it's fine. It must work for linux and ideally unix OS-family. Windows is really optional.

Comment: @msalters I mean I can imagine a crazy solution that is less OS specific, where you load the library in a sandbox of your own divising....  but that ends up with basically writing an entire fake os.  Heh.  Which just pushes the os specific stuff behind developer years of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While named pipes are usually used for inter-process communication, they also work intra-process. And on many Operating Systems, *including Windows*, they have a name that's part of the file system namespace. Hence you can usually pass a pipe name to libraries which expect file names.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @ad1v7: On Linux, you'd use [`mkfifo`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo). You can create a unique name with `tmpnam`; if `mkfifo` succeeds you pass the same name to your void file(const char *);`.